# Still get <br> in textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a text area in html. Then I fill this taxt area like this

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But in post, I get like this :

```
echo $_POST['textarea'] ;
```

===> Line 1Line 2 Line3

How can I get like this :

```
Line 1 <br>
Line 2 <br>
Line 3 <br>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

```
echo nl2br($_POST['textarea']);
```