# How to retain formatting of the content in PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following text area:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

I type any message in this `textarea` like this:

```
Hi,

Welcome to the new world.

From,
Admin
```

I save it to database.
Now, I fetch this field from the databases in a variable say `$msg` and I echo it like this:

```
echo $msg;
```

Everything is right. The message is displayed like this:

```
Hi, Welcome to the new world. From, Admin
```

All the content in one line. I want to display it like how it was typed in the `textarea`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: `echo nl2br($msg);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37610250/5447994

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change:

```
echo $msg;
```

to

```
echo nl2br($msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `nl2br()` function suggested by @saty, like below:-

Definition of `nl2br` — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

```
echo nl2br($msg);
```

Reference:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo nl2br($msg);`

And close the discussion by ticking any answer which helped you get your desired answer.